# NSUInteger in reversed loop confusion?

Tags: objective-c, nsinteger, nsuinteger

I wonder if someone can explain something, I setup a loop where I wanted to count backwards from 10 to 0 :

```
for(NSUInteger index = 10; index >= 0; index--) {
    NSLog(@"INDEX: %ld", (long)index);
}
```

This loop runs forever, it does not stop at 0, but keeps going into negative numbers. When I noticed this I changed my code to :

```
for(NSInteger index = 10; index >= 0; index--) {
    NSLog(@"INDEX: %ld", (long)index);
}
```

The above works fine, but I am curious, why the first example does not work as the numbers generated are all unsigned integers?

Comment: BTW - change the 1st NSLog to `NSLog(@"INDEX: %u", index);` and you will better see the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An unsigned type can't "keep going into negative numbers". After the iteration when index = 0, index-- becomes 0xFFFFFFFF, which is still more than zero. Easy mistake to make, I've done it myself.

The static analyzer will actually warn you about this ("Condition index >= 0 is always true" or such like.) I highly recommend setting it to run automatically on debug builds.

Comment: Ah I see, so because its "unsigned" its always >= 0 (unsigned) even when the logged value says "-10". I get it now, many thanks for taking the time to explain, much appreciated. Static Analyzer was on, but I did not see the warning, I see it now.

Comment: yeah, the NSLog line is casting the unsigned back to signed, so it regains its negativity. Using NSLog(@"INDEX: %@", @(index)); is a tiny bit more reliable since it dodges sprintf's casting limitations.

Answer (score 1):

Note that an NSUInteger is always >= 0, by consequence, your loop condition will always be true.